# Build Json dynamically in php

Tags: php, json

I'm developing an administrative system, and it send values from html -> Js -> controller (php) -> wadl, the question is that I send values from controller to a web services in a json structure like this:

```
'{"idOperation":"013",
"accessLog":{"sessionId":"'.$id_sessionid.'","userName":"'.$id_username.'"},
"token":"'.$id_token.'",
"bean":"{\"CodClient\":\"'.$id_codigo.'\",
\"CodActivity\":'.$objetoJson->cod_actividad.',
\"Status\":null,
\"ShowEverything\":'.$objetoJson->id_show.'}"}'
```

How can I make a function in php that dynamically creates this Json?

Comment: Make an array and then call [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). See the manual as it explains all of this.

Comment: the idea is not a make an array, instead of that make a function that send the parameters.. the -1 was tuf

Comment: Making the array would be part of that function. Functions don't make stuff happen with magic. There's code in there doing stuff. That would be part of the stuff.

Comment: @CarlosZ the -1 which is now -2 represents the fact you have done 0 to none research on what you need to do and is just expecting people to give you the ready to go code. What you want to achieve can be easily done with a simple array where you can set any of the values to whatever you need and then just use json_encode like John said and you can make all that happen inside a function and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createJson ($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5, $param6 ){
 $arr = array('a' => $param1, 'b' => $param2, 'c' => $param3, 'd' => $param4, 'e' => $param5);

 echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

call the function:

```
$json = createJson(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
echo $json;
```

and your output will be like:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```